# Neo4j/Cypher simple query index scan doesn't work

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have simple node `User` that has `UserId` attribute which has unique constraint setup.

I started profiling my queries and noticed that every time I perform match against `User` node by `UserId` NodeByLabelScan performed instead of NodeUniqueIndexSeek.

I tried simplest match below.

`match (u:User {UserId:"id"}) return u` and index scan doesn't work.

If I specify index explicitly everything works fine.

`match (u:User {UserId:"id"}) using index u:User(UserId) return u`

Could anyone clarify why this happening.

Comment: How many User nodes do you have? It could be that the cost based query planner thinks/knows there are only few labeled nodes so no benefit of using the index. Can you try with the rule based planner (prepend CYPHER planner=rule to the Cypher query)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cypher will use `NodeUniqueIndexSeek` by default if you have a certain amount of nodes of the same label, in 2.2.5 version it was triggered starting from 703 nodes if I remember.

Below this treshold, there is no performance improvement in the query by using the index or the labels index.

Comment: In my case for 90k+ nodes, though I have Unique constraint, neo4j going with nodebylabelscan and filtering with the property. Which in turn increasing a lot of time. How can I get rid of labelscan

Comment: best is to share your query plan, neo4j use only one index by default per pattern, you  can force the index